# Create new user and delete current user 'ubuntu' with ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

I want to automate some provisioning on raspberry pi or oracle cloud with Ansible.

Those are tasks sequence:

1. run the script with current/default/unsafe user 'ubuntu'

```bsh
ansible-playbook security.yml -u ubuntu
```

2. playbook will create new user

```yaml
    - name: create a new safe user
      user:
        name: "{{ safe_user }}"
        state: present
        groups: "sudo"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        comment: "Safe user"
        shell: /bin/bash
        update_password: on_create
```

3. playbook will ensure authorized_keys file exists for safe user created in 2nd step
4. **playbook will delete unsafe user 'ubuntu'**
5. playbook will continue to set fail2ban, ufw, Change ssh port ... but now with 'safe_user'

It fails on step 4-5 because it's trying to continue all next tasks with Ubuntu user while the Ubuntu user is wiped from the system.

Is it possible to specify on step 5 to reconnect back with <safe_user> ?

At the moment I split all my tasks into two files, but I would like to have just one.

```bsh
$ ansible-playbook security-1.yml -u ubuntu # will create safe_user
$ ansible-playbook security-2.yml -u safe_user # will delete ubuntu user
```

You may ask why I want to remove user ubuntu ?

1. It is because I feel more safe when bad people do not have option to log with ubuntu or pi user.
2. I want to understand more deeper the ansible limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible at all (not in ansible only but basically), simply because there are no mechanisms to disown or reown a running process or somehow else impersonate it.

Why you need to create a new user and remove another one, if you could rename the second in the former?
I don't know how it would be in ansible, but the shell command would be something like that:

```bsh
usermod -l safe_user ubuntu
```

If you want to delete the user anyway, you could either move this action to the last step, so there will be no tasks after the removal. Or execute the remaining tasks in extra script (playbook) under `su -c '...' safe_user` (no idea whether ansible such "nesting" supported).

Another variant would be to disable or lock the user (`usermod -L ubuntu`) or its login (`usermod ubuntu -s /sbin/nologin`) instead of the full removal.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the play as your safe user.

   - Be sure to set `gather_facts: no`
     or play will fail at this step with `host unreachable` error.
2. With the first task, in order to check if the user already exists,
   you ping the server and ignore the host unreachable error:

   ```
   - name: Check if safe user exists
     ansible.builtin.ping:
     register: result
     ignore_unreachable: true
   ```
3. If the ping fails, using the default user you create the safe user,
   give it sudo rights and add SSH keys:

   ```
   - name: Handle the error (missing user)
     when: result.failed == true
     vars:
       ansible_ssh_user: "{{ default_user }}"
     block:
       - ansible.builtin.meta: clear_host_errors
       - name: Create safe user
         ansible.builtin.user:
           name: "{{ safe_user }}"
           password: "{{ password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
           groups:
             - sudo
             - users
           append: true
           shell: "{{ shell }}"
       - name: Add Authorized key
         ansible.posix.authorized_key:
           user: "{{ safe_user }}"
           key: "{{ ssh_pub_key }}"
           exclusive: true
   ```
4. Now, the safe user should have SSH access
   and can delete the default user.

   ```
   - name: Remove default user
     ansible.builtin.user:
       name: "{{ default_user }}"
       state: absent
   ```
5. The rest of the playbook can be run as the safe user. 
   The playbook can also be re-run later. 
   The ping will succeed and user creation will be skipped.

Comment: How does Step 1: “Run the play as your safe user.” make sense if the play *creates* the safe user?

Comment: If you run the play as the existing user, once you delete it you can no longer run the rest of the playbook. On the other hand, if you try to connect as the new user and then react on the connection error with the user creation you can both create a new user and delete the existing one in a single play.